# Is there more efficient way to use the usb c ports for external display on macbookpro?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, displayport

Currently I am using two usb-c ports to connect to two Dell U2713HM monitors, as seen in the picture

[image]

Is it possible to reduce to one port? Is there a smarter way to connect to external monitor (by using some hub for example)? I don't need extremely high resolution, just good enough for programming work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your monitor supports daisy chaining over displayport 1.2
According to [the manual](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_electronics/esuprt_Display/dell-u2713h_User%27s%20Guide_en-us.pdf) you can connect the two displays together and then use only one cable to your device. (page 26/71)
Note that your graphics card must support it as stated on the page:

> NOTE: U2413/U2713H support the DP MST feature. To make use of this feature, your PC Graphics Card must be certified to DP1.2 with MST option.

I dont believe apple enables these options though, I found [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259308/71490) on this site which also states that it does not work in osx Sierra.
You could always try and see if high Sierra makes a difference.

Comment: I think since my monitors are actually **HM** model,  they do not support the daisy chaining (there is no displayport out). Also for some reason this monitor model disabled all the USB ports.

Comment: But thanks very much for a very informative answer!

Comment: Apple never supported MST and it still doesn't.