# 2017 macbook pro multiple monitor setup for a photographer

Tags: macbook-pro, display, graphics, resolution

Hi :) I've got a 2017 macbook pro w/ touch bar

According to this site:

https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-3.1-15-mid-2017-retina-display-touch-bar-specs.html

> 2nd Display Support:  Dual/Mirroring*     2nd Max. Resolution:    4096x2304
>   (x4*) Details:    *In addition to simultaneous support of the internal
>   display, this model supports a maximum resolution up to 4096x2304 at
>   60 Hz at millions of colors on four external displays or two external
>   displays at a maximum resolution up to 5120x2880 at 60 Hz at over a
>   billion colors via Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C).

If I'm reading that correctly, it means you can connect up to 4 external displays, and they can be 2K or 4K displays.  If it's a 5K display, you are limited to only two of them?

If I wanted to a setup with 3 external displays that are 2K resolution, how would I set that up?  Do I need adapters for all of them? Is there something I can get that would daisy chain all the monitors together from a single USB-C?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Relevant answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259308/119271