# MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) doesn't recognize 2nd monitor

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, catalina

I bought two Dell S-Series 27-Inch monitors and they both display the image, the problem is that they are mirroring each other, it's like it doesn't find the other monitor.  This is the [docker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QNRM45T) I'm using

What I tried:

- [Reset SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)
- Bootcamp (works excellent, I can see the two screens how it should be)
- [General info](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201177)
- Updates (there are none, it's up to date)
- [Reset NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)
- Pressing <kbd>Option</kbd> -> "Detect Displays" on bottom right corner

Look below:

[image]

That's with the lid open, if I close it, it only shows me this:

[image]

Now what I wonder is why are those two profiles there? Is it recognizing the other monitor but not doing anything?
EDIT: the profile doesn't seem to be involved in this, still not 100% sure

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you connecting the monitors and to which port(s)?

Comment: Through a docker, I skipped that part. I updated it above with the link to it @Allan

Comment: Ahhh...so a single connection.  Try bypassing the dock and plug each monitor into a port on your Mac.  This is technically daisy chaining and [macOS doesn't support it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/356015/119271)

Comment: When you say plug each monitor into a port you mean connect it to a different USB-C from the mac? Sorry you got a little too tech there. @Allan I tried connecting it with USB upstream port but doesn't work either

Comment: Each monitor needs to be connected to a USB-C port on the MBP.  Don't go through the dock.

Comment: Oh man.. more money ... yeah I was reading that just now. Thanks @Allan

Comment: I know..it sucks.  The *hardware* supports MST and daisy chaining, it's just Apple chose not to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that mac doesn't allow to plug in multiple monitors using the same port. I was using a dongle to connect 2 monitors.

Solution:

Monitors need to be pluged-in in different ports.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work for you, but my MacBook Pro was not detecting a Dell 2nd screen while my buddy's older MacBook Pro did.

All I had to do was reseat the cable on the monitors side - the pins were a bit loose and I just tightened them all the screws all the way.