# Possible to connect 3 external monitors to Macbook Pro 15" (2017) via the USB-C ports?

Tags: display, usb

I need to connect 3 external monitors to my Macbook Pro 15" (2017 version). I need the desktop to extend independently to the 3 monitors (the laptop lid will be closed, so only the external monitors will be displaying image).
I can't find a clear answer online, but so far I don't know if it's possible to do that, even if connecting each monitor to a separate dongle. Is the OS able to recognize the 3 monitors as independent A+B+C? Or will it mirror A+B+B? I also need to be able to have them independently load color profiles for each monitor's calibration.

Thank you guys.
Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MacBook \[Pro\] - how many displays, what resolution/frequency?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335322/macbook-pro-how-many-displays-what-resolution-frequency) Also - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259296/connecting-multiple-screens-to-the-2016-macbook-pro-with-touch-bar

Comment: Not quite. From the first link I get the same information for my Mac. Technically it supports 4 connected displays.
But from the second link it's still unclear to me. Could I just connect each monitor with a USB-C<->DisplayPort cable and have them recognized independently?

Comment: It can support, depending on the resolution, up to 4 displays, using USB-C to DisplayPort adapters, see the official Apple technical specifications page at https://support.apple.com/kb/SP756?locale=en_US. Mirroring is just a setting in macOS that you can configure in System Preferences>Displays.